# PIG : Assigning a calculated value to a Parameter

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Need Help on defining a previous day as a parameter in PIG.

I am able to find the previous day but when I am assigning to a parameter it is not working.

**Here is the code:**

```
PREV_DATE:  ToString(SubtractDuration(CurrentTime(),'P1D'),'YYYY-MM-dd');
```

-- This statement working in FOREACH to print previous day  but declaring the same as Parameter its not working.

MYSCRIPT.pig
**Declaring the Parameter:**

```
%declare PREV_DATE  ToString(SubtractDuration(CurrentTime(),'P1D'),'YYYY-MM-dd');

Z_DLT = FILTER JN_J_W BY (ToString(J_T_SQ::lst_udt_ts)== $PREV_DATE)
```

this code is not working,NO Output and I observed that, the code execution time, it printing the `ToString(SubtractDuration(CurrentTime(),'P1D'),'YYYY-MM-dd');`  in place of `$PREV_DATE` parameter not the calculated value.

How can I achieve the previous day date from Parameter, Please share your thoughts in Code..

Thank you and appreciate your time....

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried but from the overview it looks backqoute is missing ! 
Something like this :

```
%declare PREV_DATE  `ToString(SubtractDuration(CurrentTime(),'P1D'),'YYYY-MM-dd')`;
```